# Hashing Function for Map C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I am trying to determine a hash function which takes an input (i, k) and determines a unique solution.

The possible inputs for (i, k) range from 0 to 100. Consider each (i, k) as a position of a node in a trinomial tree.

```
Ex: (0, 0) can diverge to (1, 1) (1, 0) (1, -1). 
    (1, 1) can diverge to (2, 2) (2, 1) (2, 0).
```

Sample given here:

```
http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/tutorials/stfhtmlimg1156.gif&imgrefurl=http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/tutorials/stfhtmlnode41.html&h=413&w=416&sz=4&tbnid=OegDZu-yeVitZM:&tbnh=90&tbnw=91&zoom=1&usg=__9uQWDNYNLV14YioWWbrqPgfa3DQ=&docid=2hhitNyRWjI_DM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xAfFUIbyG8nzyAHv2YDICg&ved=0CDsQ9QEwAQ
```

I am using a map

```
map <double, double> hash_table
```

I need a key value to be determined from pairs (i, k) to hash to to value for that (i, k)

So far I was only able to come up with linear functions such as:
double Hash_function(int i, int k)

```
{
    //double val = pow(i, k) + i;
    //return (val % 4294967296);
    return (i*3.1415 + k*i*9.12341); 
}
```

However, I cannot determine a unique key with a certain (i, k). What kind of functions can I use to help me do so?

Comment: are you absolutely sure you want to use `double` as a key for a `map`? Floatingpoint calculations are not known for their precision, so getting a value back out might be tricky.

Comment: But if I use "int" as a key for the map then I will have chances to overlap between two different (i, k) points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematically speaking, you are seeking a [bijection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection). This is not a hash function in the computer science sense because hash functions are expected to produce collisions on occasion (unless it is a [perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function)).

What you have labeled `hash_table` is not a hash table. `std::map` is a different data structure called an ordered map, and it is able to use any key type for which the less-than operator `<` provides a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering). You can, in fact, use [`std::pair`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/) from the `utility` header:

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, double> table;
```

To insert into the table, you would use:

```
table[std::make_pair(i, j)] = value;
```

Comment: How can I access values like table[i, j]?

Comment: @Josh: Close. To get the value, it's `table[std::make_pair(i, j)]`.

Answer (score 1):

@Grizzly is correct that using double as a key is problematic. Maybe it would be better to use a string-based hashing technique?

Comment: How can I turn a (i, k) into a string?

Comment: You said 0 < i,k < 100, so you can simply do std::string("") + char(i) + char(k).

Comment: return (std::string("") + char(i) + char(k)?

Comment: You could also do: stringstream ss; ss << i << " " << k; return ss.str();

Answer (score 0):

If i & k are 0-100, than your key can be a simple short (even signed) and is uniquely generated with something like `short key = i | k << 8`.

Comment: can it be "int key = i | k << 8

Comment: You need 7 bits for each value (0-100), so any integer type of 16 bits or higher would do (actually, `k << 7` would work too), so yes - an int would work too.